# IP Camera streaming in red5 and displaying it on the website

Tags: video-streaming, red5, ip-camera

after googling I am finally asking this question directly. The query is:

I was given a task to display the live video on the webpage of the website(our site). Live video feed is coming from IP camera in the office. Till now what I have done is:

1. I have installed and configured the red5 Media Server on my system.
2. I have also installed the flash player encoder.

Now I want to know how the live feed can be sent to the red5 server and the video can be displayed on the webpage..
Please help me experts. I am already very late to submit the given task.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.breakthesec.com/2013/12/live-streaming-with-red5-and-ffmpeg-on.html) is the tutorial for capturing video from camera/video device and broadcasting it webpage.May be it will help you here i use the video camera you have to change a device at `ffmpeg` input.